# Texture rendering differently than in material view

Tags: rendering, texturing

Newbie here.

What could be wrong here? I want bricks to appear like in material view.

It was good before. Must have done something a little wrong.

[image: Brick problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to demonstrate what you are doing wrong with the gif below.

[image]

Basically, the lower you set the *scale* value, the more your texture is zoomed in. When the value is set to 0, the texture is infinitely zoomed in, causing the texture to pretty much disappear. Simply change the value to anything higher than 0 and you will see the texture again. The reason why it looks allright in the material view is because the material view isn't allways capable of displaying the material the way it will be rendered.

Answer (score 4):

Change the scale of your mapping node to something greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem. Disconnected colorful brick texture.
[image: Fix]

Comment: It made your texture use the UV map with a scale of 1 (default vector). but you should disconnect your bump too, or change the mapping scale for both.